RPM upgrade two servers with same packages on different days
I have two servers called test and prod and they have exactly the same packages installed.
On day 1 I dnf upgrade server test and then test if the installation vent good.
If the test vent good I do an upgrade on prod on day 2 but now a new packages has arrived and if I install that, the two systems will not be equal, and the prod will have a package I have not tested.
Should I take a copy of the the *.rpm files on test and then copy them to prod and do a rpm -U *.rpm or is there a predefined way to do this?

at job-1 I've been used to use yum upgrade --download-only on Prod while doing the real yum upgrade on PreProd Server in order to be sure to have the same packages on both Servers. I suppose that dnf can do it also.

You should maintain your own local mirror of the upstream package repository, and only update it when you intend to update your systems. This allows you to continue running dnf upgrade and not muck about with copying rpm files around and running rpm -U, but it ensures that updates run on different days will see the same set of packages.
You can use the dnf reposync plugin to help maintain a local repository mirror.

It seems like this is the right way to do it and the only way. Just a bit annoying to download ALL packages as a server only needs a few packages. It make more sense with a large amount of servers but that is how it is.
